# What is VSCode's shortcut command for VIM's ci<?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does VSCode have a way to select between tags? And I don't mean just collapse and un-collapse, I mean to select everything between the opening and ending tags.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it by installing Emmet Keybindings extension: editor.emmet.action.balanceOutward
editor.emmet.action.balanceInward